# Arquillian EJB adding mockito

Tags: java, mockito, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am trying to add mockito to my arquillian tests (with ShrinkWrap), like so:

```
    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addPackage(BeanClass.class.getPackage())
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                ;

        Archive[] libs = Maven.resolver()
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .resolve(
                        "org.mockito:mockito-all"
                )
                .withTransitivity()
                .as(JavaArchive.class);

        for (Archive lib : libs) {
            archive = archive.merge(lib);
        }

        return archive;
    }
```

I am using Mockito to overwrite with `@Alternative`. But when I add the line `archive = archive.merge(lib)` I am getting the Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Task

Or I will get

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.mockito.asm.signature.SignatureVisitor

Has anyone else experienced this too?

**UPDATE**:
Some extra information, I am trying to test this with a wildfly embedded container: pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution that I have needed. I have found a solution by including ant dependency. The problems started when I needed to use other test libraries like cucumber. 
I am now testing with an EAR deployment which has resolved my problems:

```
    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        final JavaArchive ejbJar = ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class, "ejb-jar.jar")
                .addClass(NewSessionBean.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        final WebArchive testWar = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClass(NewSessionBeanTest.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")

                ;

        Archive[] libsArchives = Maven.resolver()
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .resolve("org.mockito:mockito-all")
                .withTransitivity()
                .as(JavaArchive.class);

        testWar.addAsLibraries(libsArchives);
        final EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class)
                .setApplicationXML("META-INF/test-application.xml")
                .addAsModule(ejbJar)
                .addAsModule(testWar);

        return ear;
    }
```

And my `test-application.xml`

```
<application>
    <display-name>ear</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb-jar.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>test.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/test</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Mockito with statics or finals.

You will need to make use of PowerMock to do so.

Comment: The problem is, that I use this with wildfly-embedded. So I need to include these classes to my `@Deployment`, but I keep getting the error.